# Lists as mvc controller method arguments?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I have 2 tables containing checkboxes in a MVC form. The names of the checkboxes are currently more or less random.
Can I name the items in any smart way so that I can retrieve them as two named lists as controller method arguments? Preferably if I could do with prefixing the names.

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="xyz" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="123" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="bar" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="456" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="baz" />
</div>
```

Can I somehow get it as arguments, similar to this?

```
public ActionResult DoThis(BlablahViewModel model, string[] firstList, string[] secondList)
{
```

Currently I just check for their existence roughly like this:

```
Request.Form["xyz"].Contains("t")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the List Model Binding features of MVC:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

For a good guide of how this can all work together:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/